# What is gonna happen to math when most open problems in number theory end up being independent of ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, axioms

The way how i see it, ZFC decides some but necessarily not all truths of arithmetic, if that's the case, what are mathematicians going to do when the independency piles up? Are they going to add new axioms? If so, how are they gonna decide which ones?

Comment: Likely nobody, if an axiom is not natural then very likely it will lead to two different branches of Number Theory. Like for example, Rieman Hypothesis Number theory and non-Riemann Hypothesis Number theory.

Comment: It's not obvious that many interesting claims about number theory or arithmetic will be undecidable in ZFC, which many mathematicians consider an overly strong basis for mathematics other than set theory.

Comment: To truly know that undecidability has 'piled up', one would need to prove undecidability of each individual problem in said pile. And this is no easy task.

Comment: Well, maybe people will start taking more interest in set theory.

Comment: @ChubbyChef Can it be the case that a statement "S" is independent of ZFC, but ZFC itself ( or some reasonable extension of it such as ZFC+cons(ZFC)) cannot prove it? If that's the case, it only strengthens my point that new axioms would be needed.

Comment: @Asaf wash your keyboard out with soap!

Comment: @J.G. Are you suggesting that it would be better to use a weaker foundation for mathematics, in which more claims are undecidable?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think they meant that the current impression of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ being too strong is evidence against there being lots of interesting $\mathsf{ZFC}$-undecidable statements outside logic. (I don't personally buy that tbf.)

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. This is somewhat subjective necessarily, but it's an interesting question about mathematical sociology, and one about which there's been healthy debate on the logic/philmath side of things. I think that while a thorough unpacking would be far too intricate for MSE, this does indeed plausibly admit a not-too-misleading short answer (which, granted, might consist largely of references).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Unfortunately I typed that from my phone, so washing it won't do much to clean that filth.